# Equation of a line intersecting the intersection of two non parallel lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that if the lines $a_1x+b_1y=c_1$ and $a_2x+b_2y=c_2$ are nonparallel lines that intersect at point $P$, then, for any number $k$, the equation $(a_1x+b_1y-c_1)+k(a_2x+b_2y-c_2)=0$ determines a line through $P$. Conversely, any line through P other than $a_2x+b_2y=c_2$ is represented by such an equation for a suitable value of $k$.

The conditional is relatively easy: Define $P$ as $(x',y')$ then because both equations intersect at $P$ we know $a_1x'+b_1y'=c_1$ and $a_2x'+b_2y'=c_2$ are true equations. Then, for any $k$, we know that $(a_1x+b_1y-c_1)+k(a_2x+b_2y-c_2)=0$ determines a line through $P$ by replacing $(x,y)$ with $(x',y')$. We then have $(a_1x'+b_1y'-c_1)+k(a_2x'+b_2y'-c_2)=0$, which yields $(c_1 - c_1) + k(c_2 - c_2)=0$ or simply $0=0$ regardless of our $k$ value.

I am having some trouble with the converse, I am a little confused by the phrase "by such an equation for a suitable value of k." What equation are they talking about?

Comment: They're talking about the equation $(a_1x+b_1y-c_1)+k(a_2x+b_2y-c_2)=0$, and saying that any other line through P can be written in this form - provided you've used the right value of k.

Comment: To rephrase the converse slightly: if I give you a line through $P$ except from $a_2x+b_2y=c_2$, then it is of the form $(a_1x+b_1y-c_1)+k'(a_2x+b_2y-c_2)=0$ for some $k'\in\Bbb R$. So one way of showing this is find the general equation of a line through $P$ and show that it can be rearranged into the above (other than the exception)

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I am a little busy at the moment but I plan on working on this problem again later on.

Comment: If you’re allowed to use results from linear algebra, the two statements are equivalent to saying that $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$ are a basis for $\mathbb R^2$.